# Why does the reset password requires MFA with custom layout but not with default layout?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, multi-factor-authentication, reset-password

We have been implementing Azure AD B2C into our customer portal website to handle the authentication of customers.

Recently, during some testing, I've noticed that we have been getting MFA requests in the Reset Password, which is fine other than the fact that you need to verify your email twice, it's just annoying.

However, I noticed that in a different User Flow, this didn't happen.
All the settings on the User Flows were exactly the same, except that one uses custom pages layouts, and the other uses the default layout.

The User flow with custom layouts are requesting MFA when resetting the password, so the steps in this flow are:

1. Click on forgot password link
2. Verify your email
3. Multifactor Authentication step (verify your email, again)
4. Change your password.

Whereas in the User Flow with no custom layouts the steps are the same but there is no step 3. So it goes like:

1. Click on forgot password link
2. Verify your email
3. Change your password

I have no idea why this is. All the settings are the same. The website is the same, the IP is the same, the account is the same. The ONLY difference is that one has custom pages and the other does not.

We want the customers to have a good experience through the reset password, and asking to verify the email 2 times when they are the same step is not the best experience.

Anything we could do to stop this or have it act differently?

Comment: Are you sure you do not have MFA enabled using email verification on one of those user flows?

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to  verify your email twice the default behavior for Password Reset flow  is that you need to put you email and get the code sent to your email and once the code is entered, you would be asked to enter the new password and confirm new password. But if you enable MFA for your SignUp-SignIn policy, and then try to reset the password, you would first go by the default flow for SSPR, enter your email address and get the code sent to your email and second, once you enter the code the next page is the MFA page, that would bring up the MFA method that is selected in the SignUp-SignIn Policy

As suggested by @junnas please check and try disabling the MFA enforcement on Password reset user flow in your Azure AD B2C directory.

[image]